# PHP parameters inside url cumulated parameter

Tags: php, url, url-parameters

lets say I have an url

```
http://www.somepage.com/clicker.php?id_campaign=8&id_email=9324&url=https://www.google.com/search?q=dog&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk019eteEpAwVf2Fk4qYo7TiwhuMQ_Q:1596666153666&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiqzqf3jIXrAhUisaQKHRayBWAQ_AUoAXoECBkQAw&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=921#imgrc=M4wsJO0A7OQfTM
```

and im trying to get out the parameters **id_campaign**, **id_email** and **url**
however, using the code:

```
$url = htmlspecialchars_decode($url);
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
```

when printing $parts['query'] it only gives me:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=dog
```

because rest of the url it consider as another parameter...

so how do I get all the **url** parameter out of $url?

Comment: You need really should `url_encode` _https://www.google.com/search?q=dog&amp;sxsrf=ALeKk019eteEpAwVf2Fk4qYo7TiwhuMQ_Q:1596666153666&amp;source=lnms&amp;tbm=isch&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=2ahUKEwiqzqf3jIXrAhUisaQKHRayBWAQ_AUoAXoECBkQAw&amp;biw=1920&amp;bih=921#imgrc=M4wsJO0A7OQfTM_ before putting it in the url.

Comment: $url is variable i cant modify in any way for other important reasons, i can only change the way i parse parameters out of $url

Comment: no its not working fine, just try to echo $query['url']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ideal scenario, the URLs passed within the query would be URL-encoded, as opposed to HTML-encoded.

What you could do in your case is manually replace all `&amp;` by something temporary and then replace them all back after parsing the URL. This is not exactly pretty, but works:

```
$url = str_replace('&amp;', '__TEMP__', $url);

$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);

$urlParam = str_replace('__TEMP__', '&', $query['url']);

echo $urlParam;
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/1Iro7)